# Printing to Epson Stylus Photo printer from Fedora

Tags: printing, cups, fedora-13

I have an Epson Stylus Photo PX720 inkjet printer, and have installed what seems to be the recommended driver from Avasys as an RPM on my Fedora 13 laptop: epson-inkjet-printer-stylus-photo-px660-series-1.0.0-1lsb3.2.x86_64

Nothing will print, and the log file /var/log/cups/error_log shows the following errors:

```
D [16/Dec/2010:21:52:53 +0000] [Job 9] /etc/cups/interfaces/Epson-Stylus-Photo-PX720: Exec format error
D [16/Dec/2010:21:52:53 +0000] [Job 9] Set job-printer-state-message to "Empty print file!", current level=ERROR
```

What is going wrong? The file /etc/cups/interfaces/Epson-Stylus-Photo-PX720 is indeed empty, but why, and what should it contain?

Comment: Did you try the [Gutenprint drivers](http://gutenprint.sourceforge.net/)? (I expect they're packaged in Fedora.) Your printer is not on the [supported list](http://gutenprint.sourceforge.net/p_Supported_Printers.php), but earlier models in the series are. I've had a poor experience of Avasys drivers (hard to install, poor system integration), whereas Gutenprint drivers just work (if your printer is supported).

Comment: Thanks Gilles. The Gutenprint drivers are indeed available in the Fedora repository and work fine. I just have to pretend I have a PX710 instead of a PX720, but I expect a future update will have the PX720.